# JOIN WHERE Right Table Have No Entries

Tags: mysql

I have 3 tables product, version and Currency.

Is it possible to query products that have the MAX version but has not yet have any currency where currency version_id = the id of the MAX version?

**EDIT**

Requested to have example data.

**product table**

```
id      name
1       product a
2       product b
3       product c
4       product d
```

**version table**

```
id      product_id     version_no
1       1              1
2       2              1
3       2              2
4       3              1
5       3              2
6       4              1
```

**currency table**

```
id      product_id     version_id   currency
1       1              1            USD
2       2              2            USD
3       2              3            USD
4       3              4            USD
```

From this data, I should get this returned:

```
product_id      product_name
3               product c
4               product d
```

This is because on Max versions of the following products

```
product_id      version
1               1
2               2
3               2
4               1
```

Only product 3 and 4 have no entries on the currency table with these version_nos

Is this clear enough?

Comment: Can you please provide your code, table structure and the output you want?

Comment: added an example

Comment: @KaySingian Are you sure your expect result is correct?

Comment: @D-Shih yes my expected result is correct

Comment: use SQLFiddle for such questions to provide table structure

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use left join: and the where condition with null value will give you your desired result

```
select product_id,name
    from
    (select product_id, max(version_id) as vid
    from versiontable 
    group by product_id) v
    left join currencytable c on v.product_id=c.product_id and v.vid=c.version_id
    left join procuttable p on p.id=v.product_id
    where c.product_id is null and c.version_id is null
```